# Upstart: Job failed to start

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, nginx, upstart

**EDIT**

`status marybaked` yields

> marybaked stop/waiting

Here is the output of `/var/log/syslog` :

> May  3 16:24:39 marybakedpdx kernel: [ 3464.189563] init: Failed to spawn marybakedpdx main process: unable to find setuid user
>
> May  3 16:24:44 marybakedpdx kernel: [ 3469.342062] init: Failed to spawn marybaked main process: unable to find setuid user

---

When I run `start marybaked` I get:

> start: Job failed to start

When I run `start <anything else>` I get:

> start: Unknown job:

There is no marybaked.log log in my `/var/logs/upstart` directory...What's going on here?  How can upstart recognize that `marybaked` is a job and fails to start it, but doesnt create an error log for it?

Here is my `/etc/init/marybaked.conf` file:

```
# upstart service file at /etc/init/marybakedpdx.conf
    description "Meteor.js (NodeJS) application"
    author "Daniel Speichert <daniel@speichert.pro>"

    # When to start the service
    start on started mongodb and runlevel [2345]

    # When to stop the service
    stop on shutdown

    # Automatically restart process if crashed
    respawn
    respawn limit 10 5

    # we don't use buil-in log because we use a script below
    # console log

    # drop root proviliges and switch to mymetorapp user
    setuid marybakedpdx
    setgid marybakedpdx

    script
        export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
        export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
        # set to home directory of the user Meteor will be running as
        export PWD=/home/marybakedpdx
        export HOME=/home/marybakedpdx
        # leave as 127.0.0.1 for security
        export BIND_IP=127.0.0.1
        # the port nginx is proxying requests to
        export PORT=8080
        # this allows Meteor to figure out correct IP address of visitors
        export HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT=1
        # MongoDB connection string using marybakedpdx as database name
        export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/marybakedpdx
        # The domain name as configured previously as server_name in nginx
        export ROOT_URL=http://marybakedpdx.com
        # optional JSON config - the contents of file specified by passing "--settings" parameter to meteor command in development mode
        export METEOR_SETTINGS='{ "somesetting": "someval", "public": { "othersetting": "anothervalue" } }'
        # this is optional: http://docs.meteor.com/#email
        # commented out will default to no email being sent
        # you must register with MailGun to have a username and password there
        # export MAIL_URL=smtp://postmaster@mymetorapp.net:password123@smtp.mailgun.org
        # alternatively install "apt-get install default-mta" and uncomment:
        # export MAIL_URL=smtp://localhost
        exec node /home/marybakedpdx/bundle/main.js >> /home/marybakedpdx/marybakedpdx.log
    end script
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your upstart file looks ok, what's most likely happening is something within your `script` block is failing. It should be detailed in the `syslog`.

Try looking into  `/var/log/syslog`

For further debugging, you should also try to `touch` files at various points, to further narrow down the issue. For example:

```
touch /tmp/marybake0
exec node /home/marybakedpdx/bundle/main.js >> /home/marybakedpdx/marybakedpdx.log
```

touch will create the file if it doesn't exist.

**EDIT:**

Judging from your updated post, the user `marybakedpdx` doesn't exist. Try running the following:

```
adduser marybakedpdx
addgroup marybakedpdx
```

Comment: run `ls -l /home/marybakedpdx/marybakedpdx.log`. Does the file exist? If so who is the owner? What happens when you do `sudo -u marybakedpdx touch /home/marybakedpdx/marybakedpdx.log`

Comment: I had to run `chown marybakedpdx:marybakedpdx /home/marybakedpdx -R`

Comment: Im having trouble scp'ing onto my server.  The app jumps to 81% then it stalls and I get

    `rite failed: Broken pipe
    lost connection`

Comment: sYou should create a separate question for this with all relevant information, and post it as a new question.

Comment: I am facing this issue in syslog:- "[1808381.569995] init: Failed to spawn myProject main process: unable to execute: Permission denied"